# "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, paperclip

I got a problem using paperclip gem in rails.
I was following this tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

I got this param in my avatar `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f5f2bdafde0`
that give me this error when i'm using json:

```
"\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

So anyone know what i have to do with this param ? I tried to force encode it but it's not working any ideas?

I am using s3 amazon service for upload my avatar.

Comment: Do you use amazon s3 for you're storage?

Comment: Do you have a backtrace?

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if this is helpful or a answer but the best guess that I can give is that the string is a from UploadedFile class is returning a 'ASCII-8BIT'. Best solution for this problem normal is to do something like this on IO.

```
file.read.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8)
```

This can work for what you are doing however if you don't have access to the line of code your trying to fix it can be difficult.